# Spacing error in Terminal

Tags: terminal, spaces, utf-8

[image]
Notice the nonexistent space displayed in the first output.  I've sent this to Apple as a bug, but **is there anything the user (or admin) can do to fix it?**  Locale is `en_US.UTF-8`

The worst part of the bug is that it screws up command-recall-and-edit.  Any non-ASCII character in the command has a bogus space displayed after it.  But the space is counted when the cursor passes it, resulting in the edit position not being where the cursor is.

If I copy a line with such a bogus space and paste it in TextEdit, the space goes away.  So I don't think it's a bug in the shell.  Also, it happened in both bash and zsh.

Comment: Maybe a bug in the shell and not t

Comment: What font is this supposed to be?  Please don't paste pictures of text.

Comment: Can you run `ls -d All* | tr ' ' '.'; ls -dB All*` and copy/paste the result (as text)?

Comment: Also, which text encoding is set in the profile you use in Terminal?

Comment: The text encoding is also set to UTF-8.  It does this with any font, but that one is Andale.  Pasting the text will not help—if I paste it elsewhere, it is rendered correctly.

Answer (score 1):

"nohillside" asked which encoding I had in the preferences.  That was not the problem, but it showed me part of the problem.

Immediately below that preference is a checkbox for “Unicode East Asian Ambiguous characters are wide.”  That label is misleading—if checked, **all** non-ASCII characters are wide (not merely East Asian Ambiguous).

The other part of the problem is that "wide" means that it adds a space to the output and the edit cursor movements count characters displayed while the edit position counts the actual characters.

I turned off that option (which I actually see no value in) and the bogus spaces are gone.